# Separate sidebar from image

Tags: html, css, image, sidebar, overlap

I don't want the sidebar to OVERLAP image.
So basically I want them, side by side, I think the problem is that I have a position: absolute; in the sidebar, but when I remove it, the sidebar and image doesn't stay in place.

```css
body {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
}
.fundo img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  height: auto;
}
.menuleft {
  background-color: #CDD0D2;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.menuleft ul {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#text {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  width: 100%;
  height: 17%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F06D22;
}
.menuleft li a {
  font-family: Futura LT, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0.28vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menuleft li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.menuleft li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#whitebar {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.image {
  width: 92%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuleft">
  <ul>
    <li id="text">
      <a href="#">Eficácia</a>
    </li>
    <li id="whitebar">
    </li>
    <li id="text">
      <a href="#">Rapidez</a>
    </li>
    <li id="whitebar">
    </li>
    <li id="text">
      <a href="#">Impacto <br> na vida real</a>
    </li>
    <li id="whitebar">
    </li>
    <li id="text">
      <a href="#">Tecnologia <br> avançada</a>
    </li>
    <li id="whitebar">
    </li>
    <li id="text">
      <a href="#">Segurança</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-abstract-background_1048-1003.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add floating property to .image class

```
.image { float:right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "class" (.) tag on your CSS instead of the "id" (#) tag so try change all your "id" tags on your HTML to "class". Like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="menuleft">
        <ul>
            <li class="text">
                <a href="#">Eficácia</a>
            </li>
            <li class="whitebar">
            </li>
            <li class="text">
                <a href="#">Rapidez</a>
            </li>
            <li class="whitebar">
            </li>
            <li class="text">
                <a href="#">Impacto <br> na vida real</a>
            </li>
            <li id="whitebar">
            </li>
            <li class="text">
                <a href="#">Tecnologia <br> avançada</a>
            </li>
            <li class="whitebar">
            </li>
            <li class="text">
                <a href="#">Segurança</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-abstract-background_1048-1003.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but that doesn't fix my problem...
The image is still behind the sidebar, and I want it right next to the sidebar

Comment: I have posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updated demo according to comments understanding below [DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/k96quzhu/3/)

[DEMO 1](https://jsfiddle.net/k96quzhu/1)

css changes

```
.menuleft {
  background-color: #CDD0D2;
  list-style-type: none;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  width: 9%;
  height: 100%;
  /*display: table;*/
  float: left; /* float to left */
}

.menuleft ul {
  /*display: table-cell;*/ /* remove this */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menuleft li a {
  font-family: Futura LT, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0.28vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.image {
  width: 91%; /* remaining space */
  height: 100%;
  float: right; /* add this to float it to right */
}
```

Comment: This way the image go under the sidebar. It is not overlaping anymore, but it's not in the right side of the sidebar.

Comment: I am not getting you, It seems that image is to the right of sidebar. Or is it that you need your sidebar not to scroll with page?

Comment: I want the image right next to the side bar (not ovelaping) and 100% screen width & height

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your css:

```
body{
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width:100% !important;
height:auto;}

.fundo img{
max-width:100% !important;
height:auto;}

.menuleft {
background-color: #CDD0D2;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
width: 9%;
height: 100%;
display:inline-block;
}

.menuleft ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: middle;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#text {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
width: 100%;
height: 17%;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #F06D22;
}

.menuleft li a {
font-family: Futura LT,'Trebuchet MS', Arial;
letter-spacing: 0.28vw;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
vertical-align: middle;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
writing-mode: tb-rl;
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
white-space:nowrap;
}

.menuleft li:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.menuleft li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

#whitebar{
text-decoration: none;
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 3px;
background-color: #fff;
writing-mode:tb-rl;
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
white-space:nowrap;
bottom:0;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
width: 90%;
height:100%;
display:inline-block;
}

.image img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
}

.fundo img{
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
}


.menuleft {
    background-color: #CDD0D2;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 9%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.menuleft ul{
    display: table-cell;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
box-shadow: inset -7px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    width: 100%;
    height: 17%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F06D22;
}

.menuleft li a {
    font-family: Futura LT,'Trebuchet MS', Arial;
    letter-spacing: 0.28vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.menuleft li:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
.menuleft li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.whitebar{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.image {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto auto auto 9%;
}
.image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="menuleft">
            <ul>
                <li class="text">
                    <a href="#">Eficácia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="whitebar">
                </li>
                <li class="text">
                    <a href="#">Rapidez</a>
                </li>
                <li class="whitebar">
                </li>
                <li class="text">
                    <a href="#">Impacto <br> na vida real</a>
                </li>
                <li class="whitebar">
                </li>
                <li class="text">
                    <a href="#">Tecnologia <br> avançada</a>
                </li>
                <li class="whitebar">
                </li>
                <li class="text">
                    <a href="#">Segurança</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>                
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://wallpaperfx.com/uploads/wallpapers/2016/04/14/18521/preview_vatna-glacier-icelend.jpg" />
    </div>

    


</body>
```